# Unable to read detected beacons information in iOS 10

Tags: swift, ibeacon, ios10, beacon

I'm working on a project using Bluecats beacons. The app's able to detect the beacons around but cannot read those beacons details such as name, site... except for the `proximityUUID`. It worked in iOS 9. The issue raised after I've updated my iPad to iOS 10.

```
func beaconManager(_ beaconManager: BCBeaconManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [BCBeacon]!) {
    if beacons.count > 0 {
        print("Found \(beacons.count)")

        for currentBeacon in beacons {
           if currentBeacon.name != nil {
            showAlert(categoryName: currentBeacon.name)
            break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems like a Bluecats's bug. They got it fixed.